# A folder item is not returned by SubFolder properties after its creation

Tags: development, folder

I have a SharePoint list (not a library) that accept the creation of folders.

I have written a small utility method that allow me to create a folder hierarchy if it does not yet exists :

```
    public static SPFolder EnsureFolder(SPList list, string subFolderPath)
    {
        var folderPaths = subFolderPath.Split('/');

        var currentFolder = list.RootFolder;
        for (int i = 0; i < folderPaths.Length; i++)
        {
            var subFolder = currentFolder.SubFolders.Cast<SPFolder>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == folderPaths[i]);
            if (subFolder == null)
            {                   
                var newFolderItem = list.Items.Add(currentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, folderPaths[i]);
                newFolderItem.Update();
                currentFolder.Update();
                subFolder = newFolderItem.Folder;
                list.Update();
            }
            currentFolder = subFolder;
        }
        return currentFolder;
    }
```

This code is working the first time but if I made two successive calls, it fails :

```
var myList = web.Lists["some list"];
EnsureFolder(myList, "folder");
EnsureFolder(myList, "folder"); // same as 1st call
```

The second calls fails on the line :

```
newFolderItem.Update();
```

with this error :

```
Un fichier ou un dossier nommé http://server/sites/coll/wen/Lists/somelist/folder existe déjà.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()
   at somewhere in my project
```

This can be translated as "A folder XXX already exists".

When debugging, I can see that `var subFolder = currentFolder.SubFolders.Cast<SPFolder>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == folderPaths[i]);` will **always** return null. It looks like the SubFolders property is not up to date.

What have I to do to correct my code ? Am I calling the correct sequence of `.Update()` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple workaround.

I rewrote the method like this :

```
public static SPFolder EnsureFolder(SPList list, string subFolderPath)
{
    var folderPaths = subFolderPath.Split('/');

    var currentFolder = list.RootFolder;
    for (int i = 0; i < folderPaths.Length; i++)
    {
        currentFolder = list.ParentWeb.GetFolder(currentFolder.Url); // hacky refresh
        var subFolder = currentFolder.SubFolders.Cast<SPFolder>().FirstOrDefault(f => string.Compare(f.Name, folderPaths[i], true) == 0);
        if (subFolder == null)
        {
            var newFolderItem = list.Items.Add(currentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, folderPaths[i]);
            newFolderItem.SystemUpdate();

            subFolder = newFolderItem.Folder;
        }
        currentFolder = subFolder;
    }
    return currentFolder;
}
```

The trick is in this line :

```
 currentFolder = list.ParentWeb.GetFolder(currentFolder.Url); // hacky refresh
```

This line actually reload the folder, instead of relying on the yet loaded data.

Don't know if this will have side effects, but it solved my issue.

Comment: I was just coming back to post something similar as a suggestion after reading http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/using-spcontext-current-or-using-static-url Glad you got it worked out.

Comment: @rjcup3, I don't how my question (and answer) is related to the link you mentioned. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Completely unrelated articles, but the answer to the one I posted talked about the web's properties not being updated / a disconnect between the actual contents and the contents of the web. It made me think of this.