# Why we shouldn't use SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;

Tags: development

How should change a code to use another conect to site in Sharepoint. Which code, to change `SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;`

Here is my examplary code:

```
           protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPList oList = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"];
               // SPListItemCollection elementyDoUsuniecia = oList.Items;
                string FullQuery = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Pracownik' /><Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
                string dateISO = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text).ToUniversalTime().AddHours(2.0));
                var query1 = new SPQuery();
                query1.Query = String.Format(FullQuery, "Dzien", dateISO, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
                query1.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Dzien' /><FieldRef Name='Pracownik' />";
                SPListItemCollection elementyDoUsuniecia = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].GetItems(query1);

                for (int intIndex = elementyDoUsuniecia.Count - 1; intIndex > -1; intIndex--)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToDateTime(elementyDoUsuniecia[intIndex]["Dzien"]).ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text).ToShortDateString() && elementyDoUsuniecia[intIndex]["Pracownik"].ToString() == DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
                    {
                        elementyDoUsuniecia.Delete(intIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Getting a error: **Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))** Please help.

Why better to use:

```
            using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            using (SPWeb witryna = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Current Site**
If you're going to work on the site where your code is running (could be web part on a page) then you should use `SPContent.Current.Web` and not to dispose it.

So **don't** do this:

```
var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
// some code
web.Dispose(); // DONT DO THIS
```

or

```
using (var web = SPContext.Current.Web) // DON'T DO THIS
{
  // some code
}
```

as this is the exact same as (just syntactical sugar implemented by the C# compiler)

```
try 
{
  var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
  // some code
}
finally
{
  web.Dispose(); // DONT DO THIS
}
```

**Same Site Collection**
If you're going to work on another site the the same site collection then you should use something like:

```
using (var web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("URL_OF_SITE"))
{
  // Your code
}
```

I.e. get site from current SPSite object and remember to dispose it.

**Other Site Collection**
If you're going to work on a site which may not be in the same site collection then you should use something like:

```
using (var site = new SPSite("URL_OF_SITE"))
  using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
    // Your code
  }
```

I.e. Get site collection and then get site from that remember to dispose both.

Comment: The list in wchich I work should be Located on the site? Why I'm getting this error **Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))** when i try to add to the site another web part's elements or list?

Comment: If the frases **using** schould be before SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web, so ciode is:

`using(SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web)
{
// code
}
`

Comment: What does it mean "and not to dispose it."

Comment: You shouldn't call SPWeb.Dispose on objects you create from SPContext. So do NOT do the following:

SPWeb myweb = SPContext.Current.Web;
myweb.Dispose();

Comment: See additions to answer

Comment: So I schould never do  `web.Dispose()` But If I done it in new procedure like Button Click I should opened again `SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web`

Comment: Should I change `SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;` to the `var witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;` all times when i call to SPContext ?

Comment: So without Using, and without Dispose ? :)

Comment: YES, neither Using nor Dispose. Whether you use `SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;` or `var witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;` doesn't matter that's exactly the same. (I just prefer `var` when the type is obvious). Using `SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;` isn't opening anything it's just making a local variable point to the already opened web, which is passed to all the controls on the page and therefore should be Dispose by your code.