# Getting SPWeb object disposal

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, dispose

I have following code like below:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;    
VariationLabel label = GetCurrentVariationLabel(web);
return label;
```

Can this cause memory leak?How would I dispose this web?

Answer (score 0):

This [questions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51030/why-we-shouldnt-use-spweb-witryna-spcontext-current-web) addresses the issue I believe you're asking. The short of it being, if you're using the current context web, there is no need for disposal.