# Usage of RootWeb property instead of OpenWeb method

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I am referring a SharePoint book and I found the following code snippet in an example in that book.

```
using (SPSite mySiteCollection = new SPSite(mySiteUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb mySPSite = mySiteCollection.RootWeb)
    {
       //your code here.
    }
}
```

I read through the usage of RootWeb property over OpenWeb() method all over the internet and found that we should never use RootWeb property inside of a 'using' statement. But in this book, they always use RootWeb for create SPWeb object. And everything works perfectly.

Can anybody tell me how should I use RootWeb property over OpenWeb method? And what are the pros and cons using each of them. Actually I found similar question in here. But it doesn't provide the answer for my question.

Answer (score 4):

The Property `RootWeb` always give you the **root web** of the site.
In addition - you get **an existing instance** and *you should not dispose it or use it in `Using` statement.* (It's basically the same.)

`OpenWeb` function creates **a new instance** *you must dispose*,
And [it does not always give you the root web](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/78387/10098) -
This function will open **the website at the URL you provided to create your SPSite object**. (`mySiteUrl` at your case.)

**Edit:**
From the Reflector:

```
[ClientCallable]
public SPWeb RootWeb
{
    get
    {
        if (this.m_rootWeb == null)
        {
            this.m_rootWeb = this.OpenWeb(this.ServerRelativeUrl);
            this.m_rootWebCreated = true;
        }
        return this.m_rootWeb;
    }
}
```

You can see that the instance is created only **once**,
And from then on - you get the existing instance.

Reflecting OpenWeb:

```
public SPWeb OpenWeb(string strUrl, bool requireExactUrl)
{
    SPGlobal.ValidateWebName(strUrl, true);
    if (!this.IsValidWebUrl(strUrl))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(SPResource.GetString("InvalidUrl", new object[]
        {
            strUrl
        }));
    }
    string url = this.MakeFullUrl(strUrl);
    return new SPWeb(this, url, requireExactUrl);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure that `new SPSite(mySiteUrl).RootWeb` will not create a new instance (SPWeb) of the root web of the site collection?

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande - I edited my answer.

Comment: OK so RootWeb creates a new instance only the first time it is called. And open web will create a new instance every time its called. I have added the reflected code for OpenWeb too. Ok so now the question arises: Should't we dispose the `SPWeb` which is created by `RootWeb` the first time?

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande - See here: [Should I dispose of this SPWeb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329612/should-i-dispose-of-this-spweb) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248(v=office.12).aspx#sharepointobjmodel__spsiteobjects). (Search **SPSite.RootWeb**)